# look for keypress only if window is in focus

Tags: c++

I am writing a program which interfaces with some testing equipment.  I want the user to be able to press a button to stop the test, but only if the program is in focus.  This is because they can be using their pc for other work at the same time.  This is what I have now.

if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000)&&(GetFocus() == FindWindow(NULL,TEXT("Window name")))){

```
 break;
```

}

The problem is, the keypress is still determined even when the user is working on other programs.  I also want this to happen without waiting for user input so the program can continue running(i realize I could probably use threading but I think that seems a little overkill in this case).  If anybody knows a statement I can use in the second half of the IF statement that would be great, or even a different method altogether.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess this one. Maybe you could use the GetForegroundWindow function and check the handle against your test window handle. Possibly a better method is for your test window to handle the WM_KEYDOWN message. My understanding is that this message is only posted if the window has focus.